# Should You Have a Single HTTP Client for Web App/API?

Tags: c#, httpclient, dispose

I've read that the general rule of thumb is to create a single HTTP Client instance to be used by an application for it's life cycle vs. creating an instance and disposing it between requests.

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application.

The above is per Microsoft's documentation for the HTTP Client. This makes sense to me in the context of something such as a console app that fires up, executes some code, and then quits.

Is the same principal still the best practice when making HTTP Requests in a Web App/API? Not sure if this would fit the same scenario since the 'life cycle' of the app would be indefinite as long as it is up and online.

If so, are there specific best practices for use in a Web App? Thinking of things such as making it a static instance (if so where should it live), putting it in a service class, etc.

Comment: Yes, [Use HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) not just a single HttpClient.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Most of the examples I see for using `HttpClientFactory` are using .Net Core. Is this usable in .Net Framework as well?

Comment: This is about HttpClient in general. Both HttpClient and HttpClientFactory are available as .NET Standard libraries